# Audio Player with foreground services that works for both iOS+ Android in flutter

Tags: audio, flutter, dart, media-player, foreground-service

I want to implement Audio player with foreground services in flutter that works on both  ios + android. I've searched lots of sites, documentation, and pluggins but couldn't find anything perfect. Some of them are only specific to one platform. So I ended up creating Audio player with Native bridge. if anyone knows how I can implement this without native bridge, then please help me. I would be greatfull.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find an answer to this one?

Answer (score 0):

I think [package:audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) will do what you're looking to achieve.